# Silex auth system with Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, doctrine, silex

I'm working on auth system in silex using doctrine orm, and in this doc http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider below schema there is info sounds like that:

"If you are using the Doctrine ORM, the Symfony bridge for Doctrine provides a user provider class that is able to load users from your entities."

I'm using Dotrine ORM provider so I decied to use EntityUserProvider class for that from Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User and the problem is the constructor of this class as the first argument has "ManagerRegistry $registry".

What I should put there from silex ? Is there dedicated service or object for that?

Answer (score 1):

In a Symfony2 context and according to the Doctrine and Symfony Doctrine Bridge source code, you would need to inject the service called `doctrine` which takes a `connection`, an `entity manager`, the `default connection` and the `default entity manager` as arguments. This service is defined in `vendor\{...}\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Resources\config\dbal.xml`.

*(This service is an instance of `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry` which extends the abstract class `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry` that extends the `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry` that finally implements the interface `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` which is the type hinted class.)*

As mentioned in the first few lines of the [Silex providers documentation according Doctrine](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html), the ORM service is not supplied. Since you are using a custom provider to use the ORM, you need to inject the equivalent to this `doctrine` service.